# How to solve a double integral with cos(x) using polar coordinates?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, substitution

I have the following question:

> Let $A$ be the upper half of the disk centred at the origin with radius $\pi/2$.
>   Use polar coordinates to calculate the double integral
>   $I = \iint_A y\cos(x) dxdy$.

I have worked out the following limits:
$0 \leq R \leq \pi/2$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$ where $x = R\cos(\phi)$ and $y = R\sin(\phi)$.

But how do I convert the $\cos(x)$ part to polar coordinates? It can't be $\cos(R\cos(\phi))$ surely? If it is, how would I integrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert you get $y = r \sin \phi$ and $\cos x = \cos (r \cos \phi)$ as you indicated. Now you have
$$
\int r \sin(\phi) \cos(r \cos \phi) r\ dr\ d\phi
$$
and you can substitute $u = r \cos \phi$ with $du = -r \sin \phi \ d\phi$ in the internal ($d\phi$) integral

**UPDATE**

So $u(0) = r$ and $u(\pi) = -r$ and you get
$$
\begin{split}
I &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^\pi r \sin(\phi) \cos(r \cos \phi) r\ d\phi\ dr\\
  &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{-r}^r \cos(u) r\ du dr \\
  &= \int_0^{\pi/2} r \left[\int_{-r}^r \cos(u) du\right] dr \\
  &= \int_0^{\pi/2} r \left[\sin(-r) - \sin(r)\right] dr \\
  &= -2\int_0^{\pi/2} r \sin(r) dr
\end{split}
$$
which you can take by parts, differentiating $r$.

Comment: How can you set $u$ to have to variables ($R$ and $\phi$) in it? Does a single substitution with more than one variable work and if so how does the change in variable work?

Comment: @abcd12112144wdwd you are in the inner integral, and while integrating $d \phi$, $r$ is constant.

Comment: Of course - makes sense. Even with this substitution I'm stuck with $\frac{-Ru\cos(u)}{\sqrt{R^2 - u ^2}}$ inside the inner integral. Does a further substitution need to be made?

Comment: @abcd12112144wdwd see the update